# markerEnd not taking marker configs on the BaseEdge component

Tags: react-flow

Hi there I'm trying to set the markerEnd properties (width, height, color, type) on a BaseEdge but it says it only takes a string for the markerEnd property. According to the docs ([found here](https://reactflow.dev/docs/api/edges/base-edge/)) it says that the markerEnd and markerStart take a type string or a marker config. However in practice it's only allowing me to enter a string. [Base Edge source code](https://stackoverflow.com) showing that it uses BaseEdgeProps. [BaseEdgeProps source code that defines markerEnd as a string](https://github.com/wbkd/react-flow/blob/993a778b80cc1e80a47983ed75407b579313a73c/packages/core/src/types/edges.ts#L115)

Is there some other edge component I should be using that will allow me to set the marker end properties? Or is there some way to get the BaseEdge to accept the marker end properties?

Comment: You may have already come across this -- it looks like the docs are wrong/misleading: https://github.com/wbkd/react-flow/issues/3149

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling recently with a similar issue, here is a workaround which potentially can help:

1. Manually overriding the `onConnect` function with adding the end Marker:

```js
  const onConnect = useCallback(
    (params) => setEdges((eds) => addEdge(addEndMarker(params), eds)),
    [setEdges]
  );
```

2. And here is the function to enhance the edge with an end marker:

```js
export const addEndMarker = (edge) => ({
  ...edge,
  markerEnd: {
    type: MarkerType.ArrowClosed,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    color: "#b1b1b7",
  },
});
```

NOTE: tested for SmoothStepEdge